# Questions about errors from Pylint

Tags: python, error-handling, pylint

I'm trying to use pygame for the first time by following a tutorial on Youtube.

I realized that Pylint points out a lot of errors that I think are irrelevent, such as "C0114:missing-module-docstring". Is there a way to "customize" what Pylint displays ? I find myself with a lot of blue underlining in my whole code which is unpleasant, and I don't want to uninstall Pylint because it can be handy when I make a typo, for example.

There is also an error that I don't understand : "E0611:no-name-in-module". This is shown at the beginning of my code when I try to import a module from pygame :

```
from pygame.math import Vector2
```

This is strange because my game runs using this module without any problems. It also occurs when I call functions from pygame such as :

```
pygame.init()
```

Again, it works, but it's underlined in red and shows an error. Is there any way to fix this ?

I tried to go in the settings to see if I could modify something regarding Pylint errors, with no success.

Answer (score 3):

You can control what checks pylint does with a separate `.pylintrc` configuration file, just add one to your project root and pylint should use it automatically. You can create one for yourself from scratch, [use the builtin generator](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/configuration/index.html#configuration) with `pylint --generate-rcfile` or try finding a ready template on the web such as:

- https://www.codeac.io/documentation/pylint-configuration.html
- https://gist.github.com/rpunkfu/3cd6f8b8b23e27adedbd

Comment: Regarding the no-name in module you need to run pylint in the env where pygame is vailable.